# how to import large xml(custom) file into wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress, tried couple of plugins to import xml file. This file is quite huge. I am unable to import it. Any tutorial or suggestions?

**Edit :** format of the XML file is below

```
<articles>
<article id="1240xxxx" timestamp="April 27, 2009, 8:26 am" published="1">
    <title>Theme Parks in Tenerife</title>
    <pageName>theme-parks-in-tenerife-408</pageName>
    <imageFile>blogthemeparkstenerife.jpg</imageFile>
    <imageAlt>Theme Parks in Tenerife</imageAlt>
    <content>
        <p>Anyone taking a 
            <a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">holiday in Tenerife</a>.
        </p>
    </content>
    <summary>Theme Parks in Tenerife offer an alternative to the traditional beach holiday, providing entertainment for families.</summary>
    <tags>
        <tag>tenerife</tag>
        <tag>holidays</tag>
        <tag>parks</tag>
        <tag>beaches</tag>
        <tag>island</tag>
    </tags>
</article>
```

Comment: What does the XML file contain? Need more info.

Comment: i've edited the info, kindly suggest something i am `screwed`

Comment: Is the XML file a 'Wordpress Export'?

Comment: no its not wordpress export, some travel company wants to create their blog in wordpress and they have these articles as xml which is quite huge in size,

Comment: Okay, than my previously posted answer is irrelevant. I will change it.

Comment: sure mate, i appriciate u taking interest. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the markup is incompatible with the Wordpress import function. That leaves two other options:

- Transform the XML into wordpress-compatible XML using XSLT.
- Import the XML into the MySQL database. This might require transforming XML to SQL with XSLT.

Both require some understanding of wordpress internals. In the first case you will need to learn about the wordpress export markup, in the second case you will need to learn about the database scheme of wordpress posts (and tags and categories). In both cases you need to learn some XSLT, but that's a real valuable tool anyway.

A 'last resort' option would be something along the lines of parsing the XML and scripting the submission of the articles. The viability of this option depends on the ways you can 'automate' article submission in Wordpress. I know there's a way to submit articles through email, but I don't know how well that supports tags and categories.

These might not be the most pretty options, and you might be screwed anyway. But this is the least I could do.

Comment: i even tried using above 1 article as example, nothing happened.. i am using `delicious importer` i get no error and i get have fun page, but nothing in my database or in admin interface, em doomed :-(

Comment: The 'Delicious Importer' seems to be specifically written to import 'Delicious' (thats some bookmarking website) bookmarks. Not the right tool. Perhaps you can determine the source of the supplied XML, and use http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content to find a more suitable importer.

Comment: this is where i am having issues, i dont know wot kind of importer do i need, after all this conversation and after having format of the xml,which importer u can suggest ?

Comment: If you manage to transform (through XSLT) the XML to the 'Wordpress eXtended Rss'-format, described on http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/the-wordpress-extended-rss-wxr-exportimport-xml-document-format-decoded-and-explained/ , you can just import the file (if it's still not too big) in Wordpress via [Tools] -> [Import].

Comment: let me give it a try, office hours are completed, will do it tomorrow morning and i'll see wot happens, anyway, thanks for your help..

Comment: once again thanks for your assistance, now i am able to change the format of any given XML, problem is as you know wordpress has different format then above example xml, wot to do here ? i mean WXR format is way different than this ? wot to do with other missing nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the XML into a different format using a scripting language. I would use JQuery for familiarity [a good guide is here: [http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/use-jquery-to-retrieve-data-from-an-xml-file/]](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/use-jquery-to-retrieve-data-from-an-xml-file/)

You could use that method to then create a HTML document which this import plugin could use: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/

Or you could use one of the CSV importers and render the XML into a useful format for that.

If it is massive your browser/script might struggle but it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WP All Import plugin for WordPress.

WP All Import v3 was just released and it has support for huge files (100Mb and up).

Free version: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-all-import/ (good enough unless you need to import to Custom Post Types or download images)

Paid version: http://www.wpallimport.com/